# Expression too complex for compiler: an array with 14 attributes

Tags: arrays, swift

I was created an array with 14 attributes, then the error 'Expression too complex for reasonable time, consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expression' prompted.

I wanted to extract the data from server by using SwiftyJSON and pass into realm by using the value:

```
let playerValue = ["_id" : player["_id"].intValue,
                     "title" : player["title"].stringValue,
                     "type" : player["type"].stringValue,
                     "version" : player["version"].intValue,
                     "coverSlot" : player["cover_slot"].stringValue,
                     "desc" : player["description"].stringValue,
                     "status" : player["status"].stringValue,
                     "level": player["level"].stringValue,
                     "pgCnt" : player["pg_cnt"].intValue,
                     "price" : player["price"].floatValue,
                     "cname" : player["cname"].stringValue,
                     "collection": player["collection"].stringValue,
                     "tree" : player["tree"].stringValue,
                     "guild" : player["guild"].stringValue,
        ] as [String : Any]
```

But when I deleted one row of it, the compiler doesn't complain about it.

There are 3 more rows of data I might need to add them in, any way to get rid of the error?

Comment: Maybe try declaring it like `let playerValue : [String : Any] = ...` and remove the `as [String : Any]` at the end. That way the type of the dictionary is explicit from the beginning, and it may help the compiler.

Comment: Sorry to say the error is still exists.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are referencing another dictionary inside the definition of this one. If you save the values as constants first, you can then use the constants, and will not be limited by the complexity of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Bjørn Ruthberg (please check the comments section of the question).

The solution would be

```
let id = player["_id"].intValue
let title = player["title"].stringValue

let playerValue = [  "_id" : id,
                     "title" : title
                     ...
                  ] as [String : Any]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's actually not an answer but you could avoiding creating a massive one-shot array by creating a func that generates your array. Couldn't you ?

```
func generateArray(with json: JSON) -> [String: Any] {
  var array = [String: Any]()
    for (key, subjson) : (String, JSON) in json {
      if let floatValue = subjson.float {
        if floatValue == Float(subjson.intValue) {
          array[key] = subjson.intValue
        } else {
          array[key] = floatValue
        }
      } else if let stringValue = subjson.string {
        array[key] = stringValue
      }
    }
    return array
  }
```

And get your array with

```
  let playerValue = generateArray(with: son)//player in your context
```